# Chi2 test on a normal distribution

Tags: python, statistics, scipy, normal-distribution

Is there on python an easy way to perform an Chi-square test on Python ?
(like the `chi2gof` function on matlab)

The `scipy.stats.chisquare` looks nice but I can't generate an adequate Gaussian expected distribution corresponding to my observed one

Comment: How do you define *'adequate'*?

Comment: The `chisquare` function wouldn't be difficult to define yourself. It's a couple of loops with some addition, multiplication, and division

Comment: A theorical gaussian using the mean and the standard deviation of the observed one. I try to use ```scipy.stats.norm.pdf```, but I'm unable to produce the theorical frequencies